# Handling multiple session in directfb

Tags: resolution, directfb

We are running two applications in an Embedded device. 
The first application is killed after starting the second application. The second application is started with the `--dfb:session=-1`, to start a new session.

The two applications has to run in different resolution. So I start the second application with the additional parameter `--dfb:mode=1920x1080`.

However when the second application is started the screen is blurred with improper color information.

Kindly provide some suggestion to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not eligible to comment and I'm Working on DFB since 1 year, What you can try is running both the application using `&&` operator. For e.g. .`/myapp1 --dfb:-your req.- && ./myapp2 --dfb: -your req.`
I successfully ran two apps on Friendly ARM board using this, however both of them used same resolution unlike yours